# Basement drain not flush with flooring and old rusted drain

Tags: plumbing, drain

We are putting in flooring in our laundry room that is located in the basement. The old cast iron cover was removed and we are looking for the best option. We could put a new plastic cover on, but it sits below the flooring height. Everything is also so rusted that the old screws have broken off in the original drain. Can this just be placed in and sealed with silicone since this drain is under a utility sink and not where you would walk? How should this be finished?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please vacuum all the loose debris from the drain and the surrounding area and post the bottom picture again

Comment: I added new pics. As you can see, it doesn't get much cleaner than that unless I was to really scrape at the drain to loosen up flaking material.

Comment: Yah you really *do* want to clean that drain out better. Looks like you have ­½" of crud caked in there on the bottom.

Comment: that does not look like rust .... it looks like dirt .... you need to clean it completely before deciding the next course of action ...... just get a vacuum cleaner and a flat blade screwdriver ..... suck up the bits of dirt as you loosen them with the screwdriver

Comment: I spent awhile scraping and got the rest of the dirt and rust scraped off as I could. The latest pic is attached. So I understand, what is the objective or how will this help decide my next move? Thanks for the advice.